# API URL Returns Null

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, api, aws-lambda

...created an IAM role called XYZ with the following policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

...updated the trust relationship XYZ role to include both lambda and API gateway

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": [
          "lambda.amazonaws.com",
          "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
        ]
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

...created a Lambda function and attached role XYZ. I can execute the Lambda function successfully.

```
from __future__ import print_function

import json
import datetime

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    ts = datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()
    print (ts)
    print ("Hello")
    #raise Exception('Something went wrong')
```

...attached an API gateway to the Lambda function. I specified XYZ as the execution role of the method.

I get "null" when invoking the API

Any suggestions as to why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `lambda_handler` isn't returning anything. Try:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': 'Hello'
    }
```

Comment: Bingo! Yep, that fixed it. Thank you!